# Atom snippets package not working

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

I created Atom snippets package https://atom.io/packages/angular2-snippets-atom
however I think its not working. What is wrong?

My snippets work if I add them in through > open your snippets and paste in snippets.cson

Comment: have you found the solution? I cannot seems to get it to work too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you fixed it with [this push](https://github.com/chhunchha/angular2-snippets-atom/commit/5665a0246182f82fa76ed2d01c15312090de448d). You had a reference to a `main` file that didn't exist, and an `activationCommand` that called a method that didn't exist.

Methods called by `activationCommands` should exist on the object exported by file specified by `main`. In this case you had neither so it was failing.